# Apply Material to a specific child of a THREE.OBJ mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

here's my problem :

I would like to apply a specific material to a child of an obj mesh with Three.js.

But it seems that the material is applied to the parent mesh rather than the child one... I tried different things but every time the last material applied was set to the parent... Am I do it wrong ? Maybe I don't use the right method, any ideas ?

```
    /* material */

material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x9B9B9B,
    emissive: 0x050505,
    emissiveIntensity: 0.1
});

firstChildMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x9693057,
    emissive: 0x050505,
    emissiveIntensity: 0.1
});

/* Model */

loader = function (url) {
    scene.remove(object);
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.load(url, function (obj) {

        object = obj;

        object.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material = material;
                // How can I apply firstChildMaterial to the first child ?…
            }
        });
        scene.add(object);
    });
};
```

There is a screenshot of the final mesh with the children

[Screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug3dG.png)

Thank you for the help ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just test for the name of the object:

```
object.traverse(function(obj) {
  if (obj.name && obj.name.includes('mesh 1')) {
    obj.material = firstChildMaterial;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this now ! :-D

Comment: be aware that the `String.includes` method is fairly new and might not be available in all browsers. `(obj.name.indexOf('mesh 1') !== -1)` is arguably less readable but better supported.